# Add a string to a command operator - Envoy Access logging

Tags: c++, kubernetes, devops, istio, envoyproxy

I am trying to customize some of envoy operators. I would like to add some tags to different operators in envoy source code like %DOWNSTREAM_REMOTE_ADDRESS_WITHOUT_PORT% but I am not sure how to do it since I do not have experience with Envoy source code.
I need something like %[tag]DOWNSTREAM_REMOTE_ADDRESS_WITHOUT_PORT[/tag]%. Any suggestion where in the source code do I have to make the changes?

I have tried to make the changes in header_formatter.cc (https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/blob/main/source/common/router/header_formatter.cc) but it was not the right place. I think I have to make the changes in substitution_formatter.cc (https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/blob/main/source/common/formatter/substitution_formatter.cc) but I am not so sure and I would appreciate some help.

Comment: Which Istio and Kubernetes version are you using?

Comment: Kubernetes version is 1.21.0 and Istio version 1.11